# Error in the Pipeline because of invalid yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm having a problem with the pipeline below.
The error appears:

```
jobs stage_my config should implement a script: or a trigger: keyword
```

can anybody help me?

```
stage_my:
   stages: stage_my
   before_script:
       - echo "CI_COMMIT_SHA: $CI_COMMIT_SHA"

first:
     stage: stage_my
     script:
       - echo "Job name: $CI_JOB_NAME"
     image: "${REGISTER}/........"

second:
     stage: stage_my
     script:
       - echo "Job name: $CI_JOB_NAME"
     image: "${REGISTER}/........"

third:
     stage: stage_my
     script:
       - echo "Job name: $CI_JOB_NAME"
     image: "${REGISTER}/........"
```

I have tried changing the script in several ways, but without success.

Comment: Shouldn't stages be defined at the root of the yml file ?

Comment: I defined stage before but gitlab show this message:  "This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: before_script config should be a string or a nested array of strings up to 10 levels deep"

Comment: Check your indentation for the `stage_my` configuration.   The indentation appears to be off in your code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Your `stage_my` section seems to be misconfigured. In [GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/), a stage is a phase in the pipeline, like build, test, or deploy. Each job in the pipeline should be assigned to a stage, but you don't define jobs within a stage declaration.

So Remove the `stage_my` job declaration, and define the stages properly at the top of your YAML file.
Then assign each job (`first`, `second`, `third`) to a stage.

Your `.gitlab-ci.yml` would be:

```yaml
stages:
  - stage_my

first:
  stage: stage_my
  script:
    - echo "Job name: $CI_JOB_NAME"
  image: "${REGISTER}/........"

second:
  stage: stage_my
  script:
    - echo "Job name: $CI_JOB_NAME"
  image: "${REGISTER}/........"

third:
  stage: stage_my
  script:
    - echo "Job name: $CI_JOB_NAME"
  image: "${REGISTER}/........"
```

As noted by [Gaël J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5389127/ga%c3%abl-j) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77704082/error-in-the-pipeline-because-of-invalid-yml/77705635#comment137002072_77705635):

> Additionally, if you need a `before_script` to be applied on all jobs, use the [`default` section](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#default).

Comment: Additionally, if you need a `before_script` to be applied on all jobs, use the `default` section.

Comment: @GaëlJ Good point, thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.